# How to execute sh shell script on different shellscsh/tcsh shell?

Tags: linux, shell, posix, csh, tcsh

How do I execute a sh shell script on different shells like  csh/tcsh shell? There will be different syntax for sh and csh or tcsh.? ex: variable assignment is different for some of shells like var=value in sh shell and set var=value in tcsh similarly case end stmt esac in sh and endsw in tcsh shell.

Comment: The same way you compile a Haskell program with a C compiler.

Comment: Hi , Thank u for your comments.. But im looking for writing common script which should execute on different shells. (i.e POSIX)

Comment: This amounts to writing a common script which can be compiled by Haskell *and* C.  If you look at the common syntax of tcsh and Posix Shell, you won't find many similarities. In any case, it is hard to see, why you want to do this. After all, Posix shell is available everywhere, and I don't see a compelling reason why to program in tcsh in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your system should have a /bin/sh, so you could just run your shell script like this: `/bin/sh YourScript.sh` Note that you have to make sure your script is not using any csh/tcsh/bash/zsh specific features.